# Does django use cache by default?

Tags: django

Is their predefined default caching system for django projects if nothing is configured ?

If yes. how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your view or method to use cache, it will use [Local Memory Cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching). It has separate in-memory thread-safe cache for each process. Quite nice temporal solution.

Answer (score 0):

From Django [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/) documentation

> Local-memory caching
>
> **This is the default cache if another is not specified in your settings
>   file.** If you want the speed advantages of in-memory caching but don’t
>   have the capability of running Memcached, consider the local-memory
>   cache backend. This cache is per-process (see below) and thread-safe.